# Search and replace ID to make ID unique. Replace string in id

Tags: jquery, replace, find

I have a cloned object.

This clone object has several elements in it with ID's
and I am able to make the ID's unique by adding a prefix, and this works fine.

Now instead off adding a prefix lets say I wanted to find and REPLACE an  existing Prefix/string in the ID's

```
$clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id='BAH'+this.id});
```

How do I do a replace where existing string in ID is "BOO"

something like this?

```
$clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id.replace(/BOO/g, 'BAH')});
```

What about for class name? replace portion of class name

```
$clone.find('[class]').each(function(){this.class=this.class.replace(/BOO/g, 'BAH')});
```

Comment: your edit changes the question somewhat, and to be honest, if you need to changes classes like that, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I know the above way to change a class is wrong. Inside the clone object I have 2 other elements with classes. Am just trying to figure out the proper way to change a prefix in these 2 classes. removeClass('BOOset1').addClass('BAHset1')

Comment: That's not my point - what you're proposing sounds like an abuse of classes.  In my experience needing to use sequential classes like that indicates poor design.

Comment: That maybe, but I am learning, and at the moment I want to learn how to rename/replace a class names inside a cloned object. LOL. These class names let me know what objects to remove or update  on return from my scripts. I wanted to stay away from using ID, but maybe in this case that might be a better option. So using class might not be doable, thus I am my asking here:). I might learn something new and scrap everything and I am doing and start over. :) or not

Comment: I have been trying to remember why I did not want to use ID's and instead chose to use class names.
I think it had to do with jQueryui Dialogs, ID's on Dialog window where duplicate with parent window, When I hid an object in a Dialog Window, If that same object existed in the parent, I also wanted it hidden.

Comment: You should perhaps remove that part from this question and create a new question with much more detail in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `.attr()` jQuery method:

```
$clone.find('[id]').attr('id', function (_, id) {
    return id.replace(/BOO/g, 'BAH');
});
```